# `atob` throws "The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded"

Tags: javascript, base64

I got a problem with an `atob` that throws an exception

> The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

There are already some questions like this on stack overflow but they deal about "complex" issues (file and/or URL encoding) my code is far simpler:

```
atob("MC4wNTgxMzA0OTg5OCAwLjA1NTU0MTg5OTA2IDEAA");
```

as the string length is 41 I tried to add 0,1,2 or 3 "=" with no luck.
The expected result (returned by any online base64 decoder I tested) is a plain string:

> 0.05813049898 0.05554189906 1

I tried `dGVzdA==` or `dGVzdA` and it is correctly decoded as "test".

So what's the obvious issue I should be ashamed of?

If this matters, I'm running Chromium 81.

PS: I just encoded the string back (Why I didn't think of it first?). And it looks like the encoded string should be

```
MC4wNTgxMzA0OTg5OCAwLjA1NTU0MTg5OTA2IDE=
```

which is decoded just fine.

```
atob("MC4wNTgxMzA0OTg5OCAwLjA1NTU0MTg5OTA2IDE=");
```

PS2:
atob works just fine. **It's juste the input string (and Apple) which is to blame** according to http://www.monobjc.net/xib-file-format.html. So if ile file.length %4 == 1, I guess the answer is just to strip the last char. For 2 or 3 I don't know

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Suggestion: perhaps you could post that as an answer? That way the question doesn't show up for future searches as unanswered.

Comment: well, atob('MC4wNTgxMzA0OTg5OCAwLjA1NTU0MTg5OTA2IDEA'); seems to work, so instead of adding a =, you needed to remove the last char.

Comment: This is not a solution. The input IS "MC4wNTgxMzA0OTg5OCAwLjA1NTU0MTg5OTA2IDEAA" and it should be correctly decoded. Now I need to understand what are those extra "AA" and why they are correctly decoded by some base64 decoder but not by atob

Comment: *why they are correctly decoded by some base64 decoder* - no decoder can decode it correctly. The 41st character represents just 6 bits. Some decoders are just a bit more tolerant and decode the input as far as possible and ignore the missing end. Some explanation in an [answer I wrote recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61368242/7329832)

Comment: Luka M was right, I just discarded the last char and it worked. I guess this is what https://base64.guru/ and https://www.base64decode.org/ are doing. I thought that by adding "=" I'll get a valid b64 string. But I guess the "=" is a 'non coding' character so there are still missing 2 bits (like jps pointed). For those asking where this comes from : it's from a xib file and according to http://www.monobjc.net/xib-file-format.html Apple is to blame for the non standard behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [`btoa`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) your expected result, you get:

```js
console.log(btoa("0.05813049898 0.05554189906 1"));
```

which is different from your original string.

Comment: Yes I thought of that just after posting. Now I need to understand what are those extra AA