# DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. Payload size a problem?

Tags: javascript, base64

**EDIT:** It works when I reduce the payload size... Why?

What the hell is going on? Why did it suddenly stop working?

I am trying to decode a JWT token and I get an error. Even VS Code displays one.

```
The signature '(data: string): string' of 'atob' is deprecated.
```

How is it possible that `atob` works in another project, and not in this one?

```js
let payload = tokenRaw.split(".")[1];
let decoded = atob(payload);
let token = JSON.parse(decoded);
```

Here's the JWT creation.

**NOT working**

```js
let token = jwt.sign(
    {
        username: req.body.username,
        companyKey: user.companyKey,
        companyName: user.companyName,
        discountGroup: user.discountGroup,
        isAdmin: false,
    },
        config.tokenSecret,
    {
        expiresIn: tokenExpirationSeconds,
    }
);
```

**working**

```js
let token = jwt.sign(
    {
        username: req.body.username,
        companyKey: user.companyKey,
    },
        config.tokenSecret,
    {
        expiresIn: tokenExpirationSeconds,
    }
);
```

Comment: Seems to be a question of padding the output string, like in this case. Could you try to run `Buffer.from(payload, 'base64')` instead?

Comment: I am getting this error: `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`. I guess this is a Node approach, and not a client one?

Comment: Could you give an example of a string that throws this error? This issue does look similar to what's described in the linked thread.

Comment: I can't replicate the error. Now it works, without me changing anything... WTF is going on...

Comment: It seems to be dependent on input, which makes it really similar to the issue I linked. I'll update my answer to cover that as well; the thing is, there are two questions in your post. One, intermittent, is about run-time error (which is part of a title), but another one, about deprecated signature, is a compile-time - the one gave out by TS itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two issues in your post actually. The one showed by VS Code...

> The signature '(data: string): string' of 'atob' is deprecated.

... has nothing to do with runtime and, hence, is constant. The root cause of this is described in a ticket [opened at the Mothership itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566):

> The problem is that the two "overloads" are identical in signature,
> and **the deprecated one from node** is being picked because it was loaded
> last. If you’re writing DOM code, you should really try to avoid
> having node typings in your program, but we are painfully aware this
> is much easier said than done, and sometimes impossible.

Suggested solution is using `window.atob()` instead, so that TS will clearly know the Node's signature shouldn't be applicable.

---

The issue which actually made a title -

> The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

... is not a static one, and depends on how exactly payload is prepared. It seems to be somewhat related to the issue described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566247/atob-throws-the-string-to-be-decoded-is-not-correctly-encoded), but without having an exact input, it's hard to tell. It might as well be related to improper processing of request parameters, for example.

So the suggestion is to wrap this block of code into `try-catch` one way or another. For example, if it's a function...

```
function decodeRawToken(tokenRaw) {
  try {
    let payload = tokenRaw.split(".")[1];
    let decoded = atob(payload);
    let token = JSON.parse(decoded);
    return token;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(`Failed to process token: ${tokenRaw}`);
    // you can send this token to some server-side logger instead
  }
}
```

... so that you can always detect which tokens gave your code issues - and negotiate what's going wrong with their generation with their originators.

Comment: That's not the problem. It works fine without `window`. However, I noticed that when I decrease the payload, it works fine? I updated my question for the payload example.